# Can't use release or autorelease. Yellow warning appears: memory leaks and Unused variable

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, warnings, release

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2. I can't seem to fix this right. The old xcode works fine. But they forced me to remove autorelease and numValue release. I don't know what to do. I'm stuck here forever.I clean and analyze it. I have is Value stored to "numValue" during its initialization is never read.

```
        NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", count1o++];    
        display.text = [display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

        //[numValue release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want:

```
NSString *numValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", count1o++];    
display.text = [display.text stringByAppendingString:numValue];
```

Replacing `digit` with `numValue`.

It is not the version of Xcode, it is that you are now using ARC (perhaps unintentionally) and retain/release/autorelease is done by the compiler and they are not allowed in the code.